# Can someone help me translate the following passage in Latin into English?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

> Priusquam digressus est, Aeneas a rege Heleno quaesivit quae pericula
>   sibi vitanda essent. Ille Aenean ad Phoebi templum manu duxit, deinde
>   dixit: "Nate dea! Pauca tibi dicam, nam cetera fari vetat Iuno....Ubi
>   ventus ad oram Siculam te advexerit, laevam pete! Nam illud fretum duo
>   monstra horrenda tenent. ...Praestat totam Siciliam longo cursu circum
>   ire."

This is passage is part of chapter Andromache et Helenus in Lingva Latina of Pars II Roma Aeterna by Hans H.Orberg. I was only able to translate the first sentence that Aeneas met king Heleno who asked him about what difficulties Aeneas would need to avoid. (correct me if I am wrong). However, I really don't understand the any lines after that. I am just a second year Latin student who randomly got put into a higher class, and my Latin skill is very lacking. I am sorry that I am just asking people for help without giving the necessary context. This is the first time I am using this website, and I just want to get help in Latin. Any help would me much appreciated.

Also, if what is the subject of *tenent*?

Comment: What I should have done is: Tell you (1) to ask that as a separate Question: "In the phrase *Rex ducem ad templum manu duxit,* what sort of ablative is *manu* ?" and then (2)you could look up Ablativus in the top margin here; (3)google Latin Ablative; and (4) check it in your dictionary/ grammar.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the bare bones of the piece; I hope you can find your way from here. Good Luck.

P*riusquam digressus est* (Temporal clause "Before he(Aeneas) set off...)

*Aeneas a rege Heleno quaesivit* (Main clause "Aeneas inquired from King H...)

*quae pericula sibi vitanda essent*.(Indirect question(subjunctive) "..what dangers there were)

*Ille Aenean ad...  manu duxit*,  (New main clause "He led A by the hand to...)

*"Pauca tibi dicam, nam*... (Direct speech: "Few things I will say to you, because...)

*Ubi ventus ad oram Siculam te advexerit*, (Adverbial "When the wind drives you...)

*laevam pete!*  (Imperative "Aim for the...)

*Nam illud fretum duo monstra horrenda tenent*.(Causal "Because monsters hold

*...Praestat ... circum ire.* " (Main Clause "It is better to go round)

Comment: Thank you! Another question, what ablative is the word "manu"?

Comment: The naming of Ablatives changes even more frequently than the rules of football. Try this http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/101/ablative3.pdf  Look under #2 INSTRUMENTAL  **B** *Ablativus modi.* Translate it as 'led him by the hand' or, to show you know the idiom, 'led him by force.'